# Crowdsale creation using ethereum site

Tags: ether, mist, crowdsale

I been trying to create a crowdsale using this as (reference)[https://www.ethereum.org/crowdsale]. I have a doubt in this process (though I have tried it on test network multiple times but no success yet and hence asking this question). 
Whose address should I use in field `If successful send to - address` shown in the below screen.

[image: Creating Crowdsale]

P.S I have tried using the association address over there but all my transactions are failing... I don't know why. Below are the screenshots for failed transactions. I tried one transaction with 1 ether and 2nd with 2 ethers both failed.

[image: Failed Transaction 1]

[image: Failed Transaction 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `If successful send to - address` should be an Ethereum address you possess, it is the address all the ether will be send to when your crowdsale reach the `fundingGoal`.

Comment: That I know.. but whose address ? The guy who is creating crowdsale (in this case me) or the association's address(which is created during the process mentioned in the link). This is not very much clear to me. Thanks for your answer :) It would be nice if you can help me clarify this :)

Comment: What they're calling "organization" is basically an other smartcontract following this implementation: https://www.ethereum.org/dao . For simple crowdsale you just wish to use your own personnal adress so the ethers are sent to you and you can manipulate them with your own account

Comment: ok, so for this tutorial do you suggest to keep my own account or the association/organization they are creating that should be kept ?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get it. Thee link that you posted here it is for starting and working with a democratic organization.. I am using this part of it. "The Shareholder Association" in it. this is the 2nd step in actual main tutorial and then I move to 3rd step deploying Crowdsale.

Comment: Thanks buddy your comment gave me a hint :) The address should be of the association/organization that I am creating in 2nd step.

Comment: Yes exactly:) I did not know you already had created your organization. Good luck!

Comment: Any information if you can provide on why my transactions are failing ?